# MySQL Update query with multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in the database with records like following:

```
match_id | guess | result
   125   |   1   |   0
   130   |   5   |   0
   233   |   11  |   0
   125   |   2   |   0
```

my users choose a guess for each match and I have a function that calculate the result of the guess depending on the result of the match: 
if the guess is right the result will be (1) 
if it is wrong the result will be (2) 
if the match did not finish yet the result will be (0 default) 
I have eleven possibilities for guesses (more than one could be right at the same time)
for example : if I have a match whit id=125 and I have all the guesses wrong except 8,11
so i should update the result field for all matches that have the match id and their guess is 8 or 11 (i will give 1 for this result field)
and I want to give (2) for the other guesses of the same match

I use this query for all eleven possibilities like following:

```
UPDATE `tahminler` SET result=1 WHERE match_id='1640482' AND tahmin='8'
UPDATE `tahminler` SET result=1 WHERE match_id='1640482' AND tahmin='11'
UPDATE `tahminler` SET result=0 WHERE match_id='1640482' AND tahmin='1'
UPDATE `tahminler` SET result=0 WHERE match_id='1640482' AND tahmin='2'
UPDATE `tahminler` SET result=0 WHERE match_id='1640482' AND tahmin='3'
UPDATE `tahminler` SET result=0 WHERE match_id='1640482' AND tahmin='4'
UPDATE `tahminler` SET result=0 WHERE match_id='1640482' AND tahmin='5'
UPDATE `tahminler` SET result=0 WHERE match_id='1640482' AND tahmin='6'
UPDATE `tahminler` SET result=0 WHERE match_id='1640482' AND tahmin='7'
UPDATE `tahminler` SET result=0 WHERE match_id='1640482' AND tahmin='9'
UPDATE `tahminler` SET result=0 WHERE match_id='1640482' AND tahmin='10'
```

I want to know if I can do this job in one query?or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use these two query:

```
UPDATE `tahminler` 
        SET result=0 
        WHERE match_id='1640482' 
              AND tahmin IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','9','10')
```

And then use this:

```
UPDATE `tahminler` 
        SET result=1 
        WHERE match_id='1640482' 
              AND tahmin IN ('8','11')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this, but it will be also ugly. Use [CASE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) operator, like:

```
UPDATE tahminler
SET
  result=CASE
    WHEN tahmin IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10') THEN 0
    WHEN tahmin IN ('8', 11) THEN 1
  END
WHERE
  match_id='1640482'
```

Comment: I think this is the more prefered option.. I like it when there is only one statement instead of multiple statements

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `tahminler` SET `result` = CASE WHEN tahmin IN(8,11) THEN 1
                                   WHEN tahmin IN(2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10) THEN 0
                              END
 WHERE match_id = 1640482;
```