# Update SQL query for multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, sql-update

I want to write migrate script for my word-press blog in mysql with single statement if possible

here is sudo code what i want to do.

```
SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key =  'product' as olddata;
foreach {
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value=olddata.post_id WHERE meta_key = 'myslug_product' AND meta_value = olddata.meta_value 
}
```

I know it can be done with any programming language. But i want sql solution.

Comment: Did you try a google search for `SQL UPDATE SELECT`?

Comment: yes i did found they fires two or there times `update` depending on where condition.

Comment: [This question found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727254/mysql-update-query-with-multiple-values)

Comment: If you find an answer, then simply delete your question. Or it may be further downvoted or even marked as duplicate and auto-closed via review-queue. If you lack something, then clearly describe your intention and what problem you can't fix yourself.

Comment: okay :/ can't delete it :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use "for each" when you can do an update join. In my opinion it is a lot cleaner.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta olddata 
ON meta_value = olddata.meta_value and
   olddata.meta_key =  'product'
SET meta_value=olddata.post_id
WHERE meta_key = 'myslug_product'
```